# Difference between address parameter and contract parameter?

Tags: solidity

Suppose we have a contract `Foo` and another contract `Bar` that receives the address of some instance of `Foo` in its constructor.

Is there a difference (in functionality or gas usage) between doing:

```
function Bar(address _foo) public {
  foo = Foo(_foo)
}
```

and

```
function Bar(Foo _foo) public {
  foo = _foo
}
```

Comment: They produce the exact same EVM byte code. However, the compiler checks the ABI if you use contract type instead of address type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Functionally**: no difference.

**Gas usage**: no difference.

You can think of static types as hints for the compiler. At run-time, there is no difference.

You can easily verify/trace this in remix with this code:

```
contract X {
    uint x = 100;

    function doSomething() public {
        x++;    
    }
}

contract Y {
    function a(address _x) public {
        X x = X(_x);
        x.doSomething();
    }
}

contract Z {
    function a(X _x) public {
        X x = _x;
        x.doSomething();
    }
}
```